# Show $\sum_{k: \left| k - \frac{n}{2} \right| \le \frac{x \cdot \sqrt{n}}{2}} \binom{n}{k} \sim 2^n \int_{-x}^{x} \frac{e^{-u/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} du$

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Using the central limit theorem,
I want to prove that

> $$
> \sum_{\substack{k: \\\left| k - \frac{n}{2} \right| \le \frac{x \cdot \sqrt{n}}{2}}} \binom{n}{k} \sim 2^n \int_{-x}^{x} \frac{e^{-u^2/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} du \qquad (n \to \infty).
> $$

This is one formulation of the CLT I have at hand:
*for all $x \ge 0$ it holds that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left( \left|\sqrt{\frac{n}{\sigma^2}} \left( \frac{S_n}{n} - m \right) \right| \le x \right)
\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-x}^{x} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} dy,
$$
where $(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ are i.i.d. random variables with $S_n := \sum_{k = 1}^{n} X_k$, $\mathbb{E}[X_1] =: m$, $\text{Var}[X_1] = \sigma^2 \in (0, \infty)$,*

**My ideas**
Algebraic manipulation yields
$$
\mathbb{P}\left( \left|\sqrt{\frac{n}{\sigma^2}} \left( \frac{S_n}{n} - m \right) \right| \le x \right)
= \mathbb{P}(| S_n - n m | \le \sqrt{n} \cdot x \cdot \sigma).
$$
Therefore I am searching a sequence of (discrete) random variables with $m = \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $S_n = k$.

Since their expected value and variance are the same I thought of the poisson distribution but I wouldn't get any binomial coefficients when I use its cummulative distribution function so I guess it is the binomial distribution but I don't know for which parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything boils down to find $S_n, m, \sigma$ so that:

$$P\Big( \Big\vert \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma} \Big( \frac{S_n}{n} - m \Big) \Big\vert \leq x \Big) = \sum_{k: \Big\vert \frac{2k}{\sqrt n} - \sqrt n \Big\vert \leq x} \frac{1}{2^n} \binom{n}{k} $$

The LHS can be rewritten as:
\begin{align*}
&P\Big( \Big\vert \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma} \Big( \frac{S_n}{n} - m \Big) \Big\vert \leq x \Big) 
= \sum_{u : \vert u \vert \leq x} P \Big( \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma} \Big( \frac{S_n}{n} - m \Big) = u \Big) \\
&= \sum_{k : \Big\vert \frac{2k}{\sqrt n} - \sqrt n \Big\vert \leq x} P \Big( \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma} \Big( \frac{S_n}{n} - m \Big) = \frac{2k}{\sqrt n} - \sqrt n \Big) (\text{by changing variable}) \\
&= \sum_{k : \Big\vert \frac{2k}{\sqrt n} - \sqrt n \Big\vert \leq x} P \Big( \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma} \Big( \frac{S_n}{n} - m \Big) = \frac{k - n/2}{\sqrt n / 2} \Big) \\
&= \sum_{k : \Big\vert \frac{2k}{\sqrt n} - \sqrt n \Big\vert \leq x} P \Big(\frac{S_n - mn}{\sigma \sqrt n} = \frac{k - n/2}{\sqrt n / 2} \Big) 
\end{align*}

The RHS can be rewritten as:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k: \Big\vert \frac{2k}{\sqrt n} - \sqrt n \Big\vert \leq x} \frac{1}{2^n} \binom{n}{k} = \sum_{k: \Big\vert \frac{2k}{\sqrt n} - \sqrt n \Big\vert \leq x} P(Z = k) = \sum_{k: \Big\vert \frac{2k}{\sqrt n} - \sqrt n \Big\vert \leq x} P(\frac{Z-n/2}{\sqrt n / 2} = \frac{k - n/2}{\sqrt n / 2})
\end{align*}
where $Z \sim Binomial(n, 1/2)$. By identifying these relations, we have $m = \sigma = 1/2$. So naturally we will choose $X_i \sim Ber(1/2)$ and $S_n = \sum X_i \sim Binomial(n, 1/2)$.

Answer (score 2):

The question appears to need an $u^2,$ not $u$ in the argument of the exponential.

For convenience, I'll work with $2n,$
It is easy to show with Stirling asymptotics that for 'small' $k$ we have

$$ \binom{2n}{n+k} = \binom{2n}{n} \exp{(-k^2/n)}\Big(1 + \frac{k^2}{2n^2} + ...\Big) $$
Usually 'small k' is taken to mean $k=\cal{o}(\sqrt{n})$ so the last term can be dropped, which I'll do in the following.
Then

$$ S:=\sum_{|k-n|<x\sqrt{n/2}} \binom{2n}{k} = \sum_{k=-x\sqrt{n/2}}^{x\sqrt{n/2}} \binom{2n}{n+k} \sim \frac{n}{n} \binom{2n}{n}\sum_{k=-x\sqrt{n/2}}^{x\sqrt{n/2}} \exp{(-n\,(k/n)^2)}.$$
Use the Riemann sum relation
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=a}^b f(k/n) \sim \int_{a/n}^{b/n}f(u)\,du $$
and the expansion of the central binomial
$$ \binom{2n}{n} \sim 2^{2n}/\sqrt{\pi n}$$ to get
$$S \sim n \frac{ 2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \int_{-x/\sqrt{2n}}^{x/\sqrt{2n}}\exp{(-n\,u^2)}\,du.$$
Scaling the integrand by $u \to u/\sqrt{2n} $ gives the answer you want,

$$ S \sim \frac{ 2^{2n}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\int_{-x}^{x}\exp{(-u^2/2)}\,du. $$

Keeping the discarded $(k/n)^2$ and with the u-scaling shows that within the integrand we have neglected a term of $\cal{O}(u^2/n).$  Thus $x$ must be small, say,
$\cal{o}(\sqrt{n}).$

Comment: This is not an answer. OP explicitly said he/she wanted to use CLT.

Comment: @mathworker21 Indeed.

Comment: This is an *answer* and a good one. Nowhere in the question does it say that only the CLT has to be used. If this is the intention then this should be made very explicit! Nothing is more annoying here than spending time preparing an answer only for OP to come around with "oh I forgot to mention that I'm not interested in this way of solving it" afterwards.

Comment: @Winther nobody is saying OP said "*only* the CLT has to be used". I am saying that OP said CLT had to be used. The question literally says "using the CLT... I want to prove...". Your last sentence is a strawman, since I am saying that the OP said what he/she wanted up front.

Comment: @mathworker21 Try to look at that sentence one more time. It is stating a fact, it is nowhere explicitly stated that the CLT is to be used. You interpreted it that way, but others might interpret it otherwise. I didn't interpret it that way and probably neither did the answerer here. It is not obvious from what is written.

Comment: @Winther I just looked at it again. It says "using the CLT... I want to prove...". I don't know one can possibly not realize the OP wants a proof using CLT.

Comment: @mathworker21 No it says "Using the central limit theorem, it holds that xxx". This is a statement of a fact. It is only obvious when you cut and paste quotes like that.

Comment: @Winther Dude, sit down and read it. It says, "using the central limit theorem, *i.e.* it holds that xxx, I want to prove that..."

Comment: @mathworker21 “I want to prove that” and then displaying a highlighted formula which leads to the interpretation “I want to prove this highlighted formula” which is exactly what this answer does. Again, the question is not phrased in such a clear and obvious way as you seem to think. If it was that obvious I would not be arguing and this answer would not have been posted.

Comment: @mathworker21 I addressed this earlier: I read this as statement of fact, as context to the question, not that as an order to not provide any answer that is not using the CLT. If you can't keep your cool and have to resort to the descriptions you are using in your previous comment then you should just stop commenting here, you are way out of line.

Comment: @mathworker21 I’ve been trying to explain my own perception of a simple statement. If that is to be met with an accusation of being highly disingenuous then this is where it ends.

Comment: @Winther I have now edited the question and think it can't be more clear now.